# Google closure timezone

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am using google closure, I am currently trying to use the timezonelist class which is 
http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_locale_timezonelist.js.html

The thing is that any functions in this class depends on `goog.locale.TimeZoneAllLongNames__` available from `go/js_locale_data`. Users of this method must add a dependency on this according to the documentation. I do not understand what does this mean and www.go/js_local_data is not a valid link, any help how to get this to work is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/1fQ-GmNmLgM

> We're deprecating the goog.locale package in favor of the goog.i18n
>   functions, which don't require the mysterious locale data referenced
>   in the comments (it's just a directory filled with translated strings,
>   which is now obsolete). Unfortunately, I don't believe detectTimeZone
>   has been ported over yet, but the remaining time zone functionality
>   should all be available soon.